# Under what conditions with NSLOOKUP and PING return different IP addresses on windows XP?

Tags: dns

Inside our firewall at work, my machine frequently resolves to the wrong IP for some of our domains.  We have a DNS server that is our primary DNS to resolve external domains to internal IP addresses (192.X.X.X instead of the public IP).

Sometimes I will get resolved to the public IP, which won't route correctly through our firewall.  When this happens,  I run:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
nslookup code.mydomain.com  - I get the right DNS server and the right internal IP
ping code.mydomain.com - I get the wrong external IP address.
```

Firefox also resolves to the wrong IP when this is happening.  This will happen intermittently throughout the day.

Comment: move to ServerFault or PowerUsers and link

Answer (score 12):

nslookup uses only DNS, while ping will first look in [`hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) file.

Example:

```
nslookup localhost
Server:         208.67.220.220
Address:        208.67.220.220#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   localhost.local.lan
Address: 67.215.65.132
```

67.215.65.132 means non-existent domain OpenDNS (hit-nxdomain.opendns.com)

```
ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
...
```

Comment: Just verified, there is nothing in my hosts file.

Comment: thanks for the hint ... exactly my issues ;)

Answer (score 3):

Run a copy of [`wireshark`](http://www.wireshark.org/) on your machine and trace the DNS queries that are leaving your system and see what's different between them.

Bear in mind that `nslookup` by definition only queries the DNS.  Other applications will use alternative lookup mechanisms (e.g. the `hosts` file).

Answer (score 2):

Downloading wireshark is very helpful, but in case this helps someone, I had a problem of this nature on a Windows network. Nslookup would always return the IP I wanted, but ping would not. The problem in my case was DNS was set up to forward unknown domains to an external DNS server.

If I pinged mysite.dev using the DNS server without forwarding, the DNS lookup would fail the first time, then try again using mysite.dev.mydomain.com and succeed.

If I pinged mysite.dev using the DNS server with forwarding, it'd forward the URL (since it was an "unknown domain") and get back some garbage IP from the forwarded DNS server. The IP that it returned put you on some ask.com search page as a 404 substitute. I assume the ISP was making money off this somehow. This prevented the DNS client from retrying with our domain DNS suffix added.

Note there is another gotcha with internal urls similar to mysite.dev. On Windows Vista (and possibly Windows 7) it sounds like you might need to explicitly configure your DNS clients to try applying DNS suffixes to urls like mysite.dev:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2009/04/16/dns-client-name-resolution-behavior-in-windows-vista-vs-windows-xp.aspx

Comment: I have similar to what you've described in 2nd paragraph - when i nslookup google.com, it returns Name:    google.com.mydomain.com. How do I fix this? I couldn't find any records in TCP/IP settings nor in my router that would reveal anything about DNS server used.

Comment: nevermind. The problem was in router settings. After I removed value from "Domain name" in router. which was explicitly set to mydomain.com, nslookup started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From your ipconfig example, I am assuming you using Windows.

nslookup is DNS only.

hosts will use the normal resolution process on your system. This could include (but is not limited to: hosts, Windows naming, and DNS).

How are you getting the IP address that Firefox uses? If it appears in the URL, you should ignore that, many things could be happening at that level.